# Search Query WebPart to show people from a specified AD group

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, people-search, content-search-web-part

I was successfull in limiting my people results by user properties, but I am struggling to find a way to limit them by membership of a certain AD group. Is that even possible?

The use case is this: I have a teamsite with a certain AD group added to it's Members permission group. I would like to have a page with the people results web part showing all the people who have Members access to this site, meaning people from the AD group.

Comment: By any chance are you using a Community Site?

Comment: No, a Team Site - what do you have in mind? Would a community site suit this scenario better?

Comment: The community Site maintains an actual list of Members and may make you task easier, rather than going to AD. Just a thought. There are third party web parts that query AD.